# polynomial congruence equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials

Is there a general method to solve the following equation:

Finding $f(x)$ to satisfy:

$$\left \{ \begin{matrix} f(x) \equiv r_1(x) \pmod{g_1(x)}\\f(x) \equiv r_2(x) \pmod{g_2(x)} \end{matrix} \right. $$

where $f(x),r_1(x),r_2(x),g_1(x),g_2(x) \in \Bbb{F}[x]$ and $\gcd(g_1,g_2)=1$

thanks very much

Comment: You will (in general) need the assumption that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are relatively prime.

Comment: @BrandonCarter thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you familiar with how to solve systems of congruences a la Sun-Ze (aka chinese remainder theorem) in the case of modular arithmetic? Same story.

Suppose $R$ is a PID and $u,v$ are coprime ($\forall w\in R:u,v\mid w\iff uv\mid w$). To find a solution to

$$\begin{cases}x\equiv a\mod u \\ x\equiv b \mod v,\end{cases}$$

let $\bar{u}$ and $\bar{v}$ be elements such that $u\bar{u}\equiv1\bmod v$ and $v\bar{v}\equiv1\bmod u$. Then $x=av\bar{v}+bu\bar{u}$ is a solution, and every other solution is congruent to this one mod $uv$.

This does not work in non-PIDs unless $(u,v)=R$ (which is stronger than elemental coprimality).

Comment: How did you find $\bar u$ and $\bar v$? (Here you consider $R$ only an integral domain, so there must be a different argument than the one known for PIDs.)

Comment: @user I was thinking of PIDs even though I only said domain. [As you know, $u$ is invertible mod $v$ iff $(u,v)=R$.]

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that, since $\gcd(g_1,g_2)=1$, there are polynomials $h_1$ and $h_2$ such that $$g_1h_1+g_2h_2=1$$ If you know that, then let $$f=r_2g_1h_1+r_1g_2h_2$$ Then you get $$f\equiv r_1g_1h_1+r_1g_2h_2=r_1(g_1h_1+g_2h_2)=r_1\pmod{g_1}$$ and $$f\equiv r_2g_1h_1+r_2g_2h_2=r_2(g_1h_1+g_2h_2)=r_2\pmod{g_2}$$